Need to keep my Dutch passport
This is actually for my friend who is really worried that she will loose her Dutch passport. She became a citizen in another country not realising that she could not have dual citizenship. She wants to 'renouce' the new country’s citizenship to keep her Dutch one.
But what if the Dutch government say it’s too late and because she already had the other citizenship then the Dutch one is automatically gone? Has someone else been in this situation? Surely the Dutch government (the country of her birth) won’t leave her stateless?
I am not sure if she should give up her current (new citizenship) if there is a chance she can’t keep her Dutch one.

I recommend your friend reads Losing Dutch citizenship, then edit the question if she still has a problem she needs help with. She may want to get legal advice.

There are circumstances in which obtaining another country's citizenship does not lead to the loss of Dutch nationality.  If your friend is lucky, she falls under one of these exceptions.  If not, there is a simplified naturalization procedure for former Dutch nationals to regain their Dutch nationality.

As pointed out by Traveller in the comments, there are a few exceptions that do allow a Dutch citizen to acquire a foreign citizenship without losing their Dutch one, these are listed here:
https://www.government.nl/topics/dutch-citizenship/loss-of-dutch-citizenship/automatic-loss-of-dutch-citizenship
However, if none of these exceptions apply to your friend then she has already lost her Dutch citizenship - this happened automatically. From a practical perspective it might be feasible to conceal her new citizenship from Dutch authorities, and to pretend that she's still Dutch. But this also has a lot of potential to blow up spectacularly. Renouncing her new citizenship in particular could indeed leave her stateless, as it would be her own actions leading to the loss of her last citizenship, not the actions of the Dutch government.
The process to reacquire her Dutch citizenship is explained here:
https://ind.nl/en/forms/8074.pdf
My understanding is that this would require her to live in the Netherlands.
